# InvalidDimensionException: Embedding dimension 384 does not match collection dimensionality 1536

Tags: python

I am writing the python code on the Chromadb to create the vector database

I try to create collection in the chromadb that include embedding. during my index creation with vector database that include embedding i face this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error when I first persisted documents using the OpenAI embedding function in a file.

```py
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=documents,
                                 embedding=embedding,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)
```

Then, in a second file, I had opened the database and got the error when querying the previously created collection.

The solution was to pass the OpenAI embedding function to the `get_collection` method.

```py
openai_ef = embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(
                api_key="YOUR_API_KEY",
                model_name="text-embedding-ada-002"
            )
client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path='db')
collection = client.get_collection(name="langchain", embedding_function=openai_ef)
```

It is using a different embedding method by default and, I think, they are using different dimensions.

Comment: I was trying to follow the `langchain-rag-tutorial` but using a `chromadb.HttpClient` from a jupyter notebook. By splitting out the creation of the collection and querying I missed passing the embedding function when getting the collection that had already been created - easy to miss